Having trouble showing inequality
I would like to show for $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $x=x+iy$ and $y>0$:
$ |\frac{1}{a-z}| \leq \frac{1+| z |}{y (1+ | a |)}$.
Sadly, I have yet to make any progress. So far I have tried to evaluate the norm and show by brute force that the inequality holds, but that was not successful. However, I do not see how I can use any other inequalities to solve the problem.

This is not hard if you compute it violently
$\iff y(1+\left|a\right|)\leq\sqrt{(a-x)^2+y^2}(1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$
$\iff y+y\left|a\right|\leq\sqrt{(a-x)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(a-x)^2+y^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
$y\leq\sqrt{(a-x)^2+y^2}$, so the original inequality
$\Longleftarrow y\left|a\right|\leq\sqrt{(a-x)^2+y^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
$\iff y^2a^2\leq ((a-x)^2+y^2)(x^2+y^2)$
$\iff (y^2+x(x-a))^2\geq0$
Q.E.D.
